# $_SESSIONS in multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, session

I have the following function to get info from Sessions, so

```
public function get($_GET)
{
    return $_SESSION['user']['info'][$_GET];
}
```

and when I try to get some data something weird happen

```
$this->get('id')
Output: i
Exception: Vlad
```

and with
 $_SESSION['user']['info']['id']; it works perfectly

```
Output: Vlad
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `$_GET` variable name? What if you choose something *less superglobal*? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_GET` is a reserved name for the super-global `$_GET`. You'll probably get unexpected results if you try to use it in any other capacity. Change it to a regular `$get` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `$_GET` as an array like:

```
$_SESSION['user']['info'][$_GET['someField']];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` is super global variable, don't use it.

```
public function get($id) {
  if (isset($_SESSION['user']['info'][$id])){
    return $_SESSION['user']['info'][$id];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the argument you are passing to the function.
Replace `$_GET` by any other variable